# VBA Run-time error 424 Object required when using SmartArt node

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I keep on getting this error for my code and I don't know what is the problem with it.

```
Function vAddNode(oShp As Shape, iID As Integer, sText As String) As SmartArtNode
    Dim oNode As SmartArtNode
    Set oNode = oShp.SmartArt.Nodes(iID).AddNode
    oNode.Demote
    oNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = sText
    Set vAddNode = oNode
End Function
```

I keep on getting the error at the line:

```
oNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = sText
```

When I add the watch, i keep on seeing that oNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text keeps on getting the type of Integer instead of String as it should be.

When i use the function in the code, I use it the following way:

```
Set oNodeInRAM = vAddNode(oShp, 1, "RAM")
```

where oShp is initially: `Dim oShp As Shape` and then when a SmartArt shape is found within the slide, it is set as: `Set oShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(slideno).Shapes(i)`

Can anyone please help me with this? I've been looking over this for few days now... Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which SmartArt Layout are you using? Is this specific for this layout or does it happen with all layouts?

Comment: It happens to all layouts I tried out. I'm currently using the Grouped List layout

Comment: It works fine for me... I used the first suggested layout in my test. You'll need to provide more information if you want us to repro...